# Grouping data by frequency

Tags: python, group-by, timestamp, time-series

I did a code which generates random numbers below and i save them in a csv which look like below, I am trying to play around and learn the group by function. I would like for instance do the sum or average of those group by timestamp. I am new in Python, i cannot find anywhere to start though. Ulitmately i would like to do the same but for 1min or 5min (every 5min starting from 00:00:00, not enough data in my example below but that would do something like 13:35:00 to 13:40:00 and the next one 13:40:00 included to 13:45:00 excluded, etc), i think i could figure out the 1min in extracting the minute part from the timestamp but the 5min seems complex. Not asking for a copy paste of a code, but i have no idea where to start to be honest.

```
Level   Timestamp
99  03/04/2013 13:37:20
98  03/04/2013 13:37:20
98  03/04/2013 13:37:20
99  03/04/2013 13:37:20
105 03/04/2013 13:37:20
104 03/04/2013 13:37:20
102 03/04/2013 13:37:21
102 03/04/2013 13:37:21
103 03/04/2013 13:37:22
82  03/04/2013 13:37:23
83  03/04/2013 13:37:23
82  03/04/2013 13:37:23
83  03/04/2013 13:37:23
54  03/04/2013 13:37:24
55  03/04/2013 13:37:24
54  03/04/2013 13:37:24
55  03/04/2013 13:37:24
56  03/04/2013 13:37:25
57  03/04/2013 13:37:25
```

Comment: Just a quibble - it looks like it's tab-separated, rather than comma-separated (csv stands for comma separated values).

Comment: Otherwise, I'm a little confused by what you're trying to accomplish - could you give an example of what the resulting dataset would look like?

Comment: im trying to get only one line by timestamp, whatever if this is a sum or average

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it can be done with itertools
http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby

but be care:

> It generates a break or new group every time the value of the key
>   function changes (which is why it is usually necessary to have sorted
>   the data using the same key function).

An example usage:

if your data have been processed as a list of Level , timestamp pair.

```
data = [(99, '03/04/2013 13:37:20'), (98,  '03/04/2013 13:37:20'), ...]
```

And you would like to AVG the group by the data with 5mins interval

```
data.sort(key=lambda i: i[1]) # sort with timestamp
results = []

def keyfunc(timestamp, interval = 5*60):
    # defined a key function.
    # 1. parse the datetime string to datetime object
    # 2. count the time delta (seconds)
    # 3. divided the time delta with interval, which is (6*60) here
    xt = datetime(2013, 4,3)
    dt = datetime.strptime(timestamp, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
    delta_second = int((dt - xt).total_seconds())
    normalize_second = (delta_second / interval) * interval
    return xt + timedelta(seconds=normalize_second)

for k, g in groupby(data, key=lambda i: keyfunc(i[1])):
    # k would be time interval "03/04/2013 13:30:00", "03/04/2013 13:35:00" .... 
    # g would be the level, timestamp pair belong to the interval
    avg_level = sum([x[0] for x in g]) / len(g)
    results.append((k, avg_level))
```

## EDIT1

The `keyfunc` used in groupby function tells how to divided items into group.
If two items have the same return value of key function, they will be placed in the same group.
(only if these items are sorted)

```
>>> keyfunc('03/04/2013 13:37:20')
datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 3, 13, 35)

>>> keyfunc('03/04/2013 13:37:30')
datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 3, 13, 35)

# the return value are the same, so 03/04/2013 13:37:20 and 03/04/2013 13:37:30
# will be consider in the same group.
```

Comment: lucemia, sorry but i am struggling to understand what is the purpose of the keyfunc, I think it is because the groupby needs a function as a key? However as it is you give the xt as initial date, then you provide the timestamp of your serie as argument and it returns the timestamp of your serie? Surely i must be missing something.. i think there is also a slight discrepancy on dt= and also normalize_second = why divide and then multiply by the interval?

Comment: the keyfunc tells python how to divid these items. It can be divided in serval ways thus we need to specify the right way. See my Edit

Comment: What do mean by right way? Divide the timestamp by the interval?

Comment: right, you must tell the groupby function to divide the timestamp with 1 minutes, 5 minutes, 10 minutes, 30 minutes or ... etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to approach this, but you're effectively "binning" on the times. I would approach it in a few steps:

You don't want to parse the time yourself with string manipulation, it will blow up in your face; trust me! Parse out the timestamp into a datetime object (google should give you a pretty good answer).  Once you have that, you can do lots of fun stuff like compare two times.

Now that you have the datetime objects, you can start to "bin" them. I'm going to assume the records are in order. Start with the first record's time of "03/04/2013 13:37:20" and create a new datetime object at "03/04/2013 13:37:00" [hint: set seconds=0 on the datetime object you read in]. This is the start of your first "bin". Now add one minute to your start datetime [hint: endDT = startDT + timedelta(seconds=60)], that's the end of your first bin.

Now start going through your records checking if the record is less than your endDT, if it is, add it to a list for that bin. If the record is greater than your endDT, you're in the next bin. To start the new bin, add one minute to your endDT and create a new list to hold those items and keep chugging along in your loop.

Once you go through the loop, you can run max/min/avg on the lists. Ideally, you'll store the lists in a dictionary that looks like {datetimeObject : [34, 23, 45, 23]}. It'll make printing and sorting easy.

This isn't the most efficient/flexible/cool way to do it, but I think it's probably the most helpful to start with.